# Unresolved reference: count error (Kotlin Function)

Tags: function, kotlin

I am newly learning kotlin, and I am playing in the Playground that kotlin created. As I was following the demo practice, I got these errors.
"Unresolved reference: count"
"Unresolved reference: count"
I don't understand why because I exactly mimicked the demo that is in the Example on the website.

```
fun generateAnswerMachine(countThreshold: Int): String {
val answerMachine = if (count < countThreshold) {
    "I have the answer."
} else {
    "The andswer eludes me"
}

return answerMachine 
}

val answerString = generateAnswerMachine(42)
```

Also,

```
fun generateAnswerString(countThreshold: Int): String = if (count > countThreshold) {
    "I have the answer"
} else {
    "The answer eludes me"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta define `count` before using it in your function, like `var count = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the response! It worked out, but I have one more question. In the first function that I wrote I think I get it where I can define var count properly since the line looks orderly. But how can I define var count in the second function? (I saw they are interchangeable)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve exactly, but you can also add count in the parameters of your function, like: `fun generateAnswerString(countThreshold: Int, count: Int): String`